# Multiple VM Creation by ARM Powershell approach

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-powershell, azure-resource-manager

I have a ps workflow(.psm file) where I am trying to create 5 vms in parallel. I am using ARM cmdlets.I am getting an error-

> Error- Cannot validate argument on parameter 'SubnetId'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command 
>   again.

Here is my challange-

1. Even if I remove `-parallel` parameter from `foreach` even then its not making any difference.
2. If I run the same code NOT inside a workflow(ps1 file) removing `-parralel` parameter I am able to
   create 5 vms

Code-

```
workflow Create-VMs
{
    $UserName = "abc@cde.onmicrosoft.com"
    $pwd = ConvertTo-SecureString "xxxxxxxx" -AsPlainText -Force
    $AzureCredential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($UserName, $pwd) 
    login-azurermaccount -credential $AzureCredential
    Add-AzureRmAccount -Credential $AzureCredential
    Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionName "xxxxx"

    $virtualNetworkName = "myvpn"
    $locationName = "East US"
    $ResourceGroupName = "myrg"
    $user = "adminuser"
    $password = "AdminPass123"
    $VMSize = "Standard_D2"
    $sourcevhd = "https://abc.blob.core.windows.net/vhds/windowsserver2008.vhd"
    $virtualNetwork = Get-AzureRmVirtualNetwork -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Name $virtualNetworkName

    foreach -parallel($i in 1..5)
    {
        $VMName = "myname" + $i
        $destinationVhd = "https://abc.blob.core.windows.net/vhds/windowsserver2008" + $i + ".vhd"
        $staticip = "dynamicip" + $i
        $virtualNetwork = Get-AzureRmVirtualNetwork -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Name $virtualNetworkName
        $publicIp = New-AzureRmPublicIpAddress -Name $staticip -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Location $locationName -AllocationMethod Dynamic
        $networkInterface = New-AzureRmNetworkInterface -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Name $VMName -Location $locationName -SubnetId $virtualNetwork.Subnets[0].Id -PublicIpAddressId $publicIp.Id
        $vmConfig = New-AzureRmVMConfig -VMName $VMName -VMSize $VMSize
        $vmConfig = Set-AzureRmVMOSDisk -VM $vmConfig -Name $VMName -VhdUri $destinationVhd -CreateOption FromImage -Windows -SourceImageUri $sourcevhd
        $vmConfig = Add-AzureRmVMNetworkInterface -VM $vmConfig -Id $networkInterface.Id
        $securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force
        $cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($user, $securePassword) 
        Set-AzureRmVMOperatingSystem -VM $vmConfig -Windows -Credential $cred -ProvisionVMAgent -ComputerName $VMName
        New-AzureRmVM -VM $vmConfig -Location $locationName -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName
    }
}
```

---

Not able to find out what is the actual problem. Any other approach for creating multiple vms in parallel using ARM ?

Answer (score -1):

I've not had much luck with -parallel and the Azure cmdlets, but I can think of two options for you:

1) use PowerShell jobs - this would require you to login for each job, here's a snippet of how I do it - the "job" in this case is removing a resource group.

```
foreach ($AzureResourceGroup in $AzureResourceGroups) {
  Start-Job -Name $AzureResourceGroup {
    Param($AzureResourceGroup, $creds, $tenantID, $subscriptionName)
      Login-AzureRmAccount -ServicePrincipal -Credential $creds -TenantId $tenantId
      Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionName $subscriptionName
      Remove-AzureRMResourceGroup -Force -Verbose -Name $AzureResourceGroup
  } -ArgumentList $AzureResourceGroup, $creds, $tenantId, $subscriptionName 
}
Get-Job | Wait-Job | Receive-Job
```

2) I think better way would be to use a JSON template, and have Azure orchestrate the deployment.  There's a sample of how of the template and how to do it here: https://github.com/bmoore-msft/AzureRM-Samples/tree/master/VMFromImageMulti - there's a readme in the root to show how to deploy it.